# Merge Two Polygons Using Editor merge in arcGis

Tags: polygon, arcgis-engine, merge, standard-license-level

i want to create a ArcEngine  function using .net that allow to do the same thing like (see picture):
[image]

- select 2 polygons
- click merge

Is there somebody who can help please!!
Sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello i found the the answer by self :

Private Sub mergeFeatures()

```
Dim mergee As IFeature 'first ifeature
Dim merger As IFeature 'second ifeature

mergee = featureLayerParcelle.FeatureClass.GetFeature(8) 'get the ifeature that has objectid=8
merger = featureLayerParcelle.FeatureClass.GetFeature(9) 'get the ifeature that has objectid=9
Dim union As ITopologicalOperator = CType(mergee.Shape, ITopologicalOperator) 'itopological variable
StarEditLayer(featureLayerParcelle) ' start editing
mergee.Shape = union.Union(merger.Shape) ' the first ifeature set it geometry with the union of the tow features
merger.Delete() ' delete second ifeature
mergee.Store() 'save 
pEditor.StopEditing(True) 'stop editing and save 
AxMapControl1.CurrentTool = Nothing
```

End Sub

so you can personalize it : get object id when we clique and start fusion